# How to create new String using a lambda function?

Tags: java, lambda

I would like to call method `setValue()` that needs String parameter -- it checks if it's possible to convert to integer and increase it by 1, converts back to String or uses the original value:

```
String origStr  = "123";
MyClass.setValue(() -> {
    String val = origStr;
    try
    {
        val = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(origStr) + 1);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {}
    return val;
});
```

However it is not possible, I get "*Target type of a lambda conversion must be an interface"* from compiler.

Any idea how to create this String?

Edit: why am I trying to do it like this? Actually I use builder pattern and I'd like to set it without temporary values:

```
MYClass x = new MyClass.Builder
.setValue()  // here's my code
.setSomethingElse()
.setOneMoreTime()
.build();
```

Comment: As `setValue()` takes a `String` parameter, you can't pass a lambda there. It would have to take for example a `Supplier<String>`. But most importantly, why are you trying to do this? The logic seems really weird for a setter.

Comment: I've updated it with more realistic usage explaining why I am trying to do it this way.

Comment: Why do you increase it if the String is a valid number? Why is a non-number a valid input? Currently the variable seems to be some weird "string/number" hybrid. It's not very good design to use Strings like that.

Comment: @Kayaman I need to distinguish slot positions. Sometimes I don't get integer slot number but I get a text representation - it means the occupied slot can be anywhere but I need to distinguish it somehow. It is not something I can affect, it's my input I must work with.

Comment: Of course you can affect it, you're the programmer. Just because the input is something doesn't mean you're forced to do something. Maybe the input warrants its own `SlotPosition` type which wraps a `String` and the related functionality, for example. There are design advantages to be had from that (stronger typing) and you can still convert to/from `String` as necessary, for input / storage.

Answer (score 5):

There’s no need for a lambda here. Just execute the code before calling `setValue`:

```
String origStr  = "123";
String val = origStr;
try {
    val = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(origStr) + 1);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {}

MyClass.setValue(val);
```

If you want to avoid the temporary due to chaining, the closest you can get is the following, which I’d strongly recommend against, due to it being pretty illegible:

```
final String origStr = "123";
setValue(((Supplier<String>) () -> {
    String val = origStr;
    try {
        val = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(origStr) + 1);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {}
    return val;
}).get());
```

The idea here is to define a lambda and immediately invoke it — this pattern is known as [*immediately invoked function expression*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) (IIFE) and is somewhat common in other languages (notably JavaScript and C++) to limit scope. But unfortunately Java syntactically doesn’t allow invoking a lambda directly; you first have to cast it to a suitable functional interface type, and then invoke its `get()` method, which makes the whole thing rather convoluted. Better to use a regular method.

Comment: My goal was to set MyClass without creating temporary variables. I've updated it with more realistic usage explaining why I am trying to do it this way.

Comment: @MichalŠpondr Ah I see. In that case you’d use an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) in other languages. But unfortunately Java currently doesn’t support this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to use lambda here. However, you can do this if you want.

```
class MyClass {
    static private String value;

    static void setValue(Supplier<String> supplier) {
       value = supplier.get();
    }
}
```

Now you can pass any function reference (and lambda) to this method that has no arguments and returns a string.

```
MyClass.setValue(() -> {
   String val = origStr;
   try {
      val = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(origStr) + 1);
   } catch(NumberFormatException e) {}
      return val;
});
```

will works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want like this.

```
String origStr  = "123";
Supplier<String> inc = () -> {
    String val = origStr;  // must be effective final
    try
    {
        val = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(origStr) + 1);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {}
    return val;
};

String v = inc.get();
System.out.println(v);
```

Prints

```
124
```

Or if you supply the string as an argument.

```
UnaryOperator<String> inc1 = str-> {
    try
    {
        str = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(origStr) + 1);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {}
    return str;
};

String result = inc1.apply("123");
System.out.println(result);
```

Prints

```
124
```

Answer (score 0):

If your method must absolutely take a String and a function:

- Let's consider your method setValue

```
    private static String setValue(String t, Function<String, String> f) {
        return f.apply(t);
    }
```

- So you will need an String param and a lambda this way :

```
         String origStr  = "123";
         IcarSubscriptionApplication.setValue(origStr, (String s) -> {
             String val = origStr;
             try
             {
                 val = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(s) + 1);
             } catch(NumberFormatException e) {}
             return val;
         });
```